# create windows service from executable JAR file

Tags: java, service, jar, windows-services

I am trying to create service from JAR file and after some research I was able to create window service using SC

```
sc create "ServiceName" binPath= "PathToJava.exe -jar PathToJarFile"
```

but when I tried to start the service it displayed the bellow error

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Can anyone help me out regarding this, any help is valuable